# Special characters cause title to cut off in tweet box using share button

Tags: javascript, html, share

I have created a share button using some javascript.  It grabs my title and url from my blog and pastes it into the tweet box (its not twitter), but the problem comes in when there is an "&" sign in the post title and it just completely cuts off before that "&" sign in the share box.

For example if the title is: "The Dog Blog: My Dog & I walking" and the URL is "www.mydogandme.com" .. it should grab both and paste them in their entirety into the share box but it cuts off at "The Dog Blog: My Dog" because of the "&".

Does anyone know how I can either just ignore any "&" signs so it will skip over it and continue to grab and paste the rest of the title and URL? or anything else that would solve this?

Thanks for any help

Javascript

```
<div class='stocktwits-share'>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var text = 'via @handle';
    var space = ' ';

    function stockTiwtsShare() {
        newShareWindow = window.open('https://stocktwits.com/widgets/share?body=' + document.title + space + text + space + document.URL, '', 'width=200', 'height=100');
        newShareWindow.focus(5000);
    }
</script>
<br />
<img src="http://imageshack.com/a/img542/4766/bsxz.png" onclick='stockTiwtsShare()' />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to [URI encode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) each component used in a query string, eg

```
var paramString = encodeURIComponent([document.title, text, document.URL].join(' '));
```

Then use it in your URL

```
window.open('https://stocktwits.com/widgets/share?body=' + paramString, '', 'width=200', 'height=100');
```

JSFiddle example here - http://jsfiddle.net/A3jL6/

Comment: thanks for the quick response.. i am really a beginner at JavaScript and have no idea how to do that yet, im lost trying to figure out the moz page.. do you think you could do a jsfiddle? would be awesome

Comment: @trade2day1 Err, I've given you a concrete example and a JSFiddle demo already. Not sure what else there is to understand

Comment: lol i got it.. just didnt put 2 and 2 together.. gotta give me a break, ive been coding for 2 months and moving into JS just now.. happy holidays to u